# Searching in List properties

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an entity called 'Profile' which has a property by name 'keySkills' of type List.

If 'keySkills' has values like [Java,C,C++,WEB TECHNOLOGIES], how do I search entities 
when search criteria is just WEB ? the following query filter does not work because the input'WEB' is not matching with value 'WEB TECHNOLOGIES' in the list.

```
       ArrayList criteria=new ArrayList();
       criteria.add("WEB");
       q.addFilter("keySkills",FilterOperator.IN, criteria);
```

Thanks
 Ma

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you cannot use an ArrayList as a search parameter. it should be:

```
 q.addFilter("keySkills",FilterOperator.IN, "WEB");
```

Second, you cannot do what you described using IN operator. It has to match a value exactly, or it will return no results.

You can use a [Search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/) for this kind of search.

Comment: I can pass at least a List type object  List<String> findSkills = Arrays.asList("Java","WEB"); It is working if list has only WEB as value. Which search API can you please point to right link..

Comment: Hi Andrei, My application is a job portal where recruiters will search  candidates based on some key words. This is usecase where I need a pattern matching capability. Creating Document and Indexing would simply mean more cost of hosting for me.my application is still in Development stage I am planning to shift to Red Hat OpenShift (Jboss + MySQL ) platform. what do you suggest me?

Comment: Probably I have to fetch all entities and do a java string search for pattern match. have to build some memcache if I am fetching all entities I believe...

Answer (score -1):

You can use a normal equality operator to check a match against a single value in a multi-valued field.

Comment: He wants a partial match.